# How can I run complicated commands on establishing a mosh connection?

Tags: shell, ssh, tmux, mosh

With ssh I can do this:

```
ssh REMOTE -t 'tmux a || tmux'
```

With mosh the best I can do is this:

```
mosh REMOTE -- tmux a
```

But this won't work:

```
mosh REMOTE -- tmux a || tmux
```

Neither does this: (It doesn't matter whether it's single quote or double quote, I tried both)

```
mosh REMOTE -- 'tmux a || tmux'
```

So, my question is: How am I supposed to do this job?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, it seems that I have to explicitly use a shell to execute command:

```
mosh REMOTE -- sh -c 'tmux a || tmux'
```

---

**EDIT**

Instead of doing `tmux a || tmux`, a better way is add `new-session` to `~/.tmux.conf` and just run `tmux`. That would make things much easier. I can do things like this now:

```
mosh REMOTE -- tmux
```

Awesome!

Comment: I think that what you want in the  second solution is `most remote -- tmux a` otherwise it will create a new session every time instead of attaching to the one that already exists.

Comment: you can also do `tmux new-session -A -s somenameforsession`

Comment: dunno if it changed since you answered but nowadays it's `mosh [options] -- user@host [command]` you put remote before -- :)

Answer (score 3):

There might be more complicated commands than the examples given above. I wanted to make a command that reattaches to an existing tmux session if one exists but is not already attached, or a new one if there are none available.

Looking at [this example](https://superuser.com/questions/487363/tmux-equivalent-of-screen-r/702345#702345), I would have done something like this:

```
function tmosh() {
    mosh $1 -- (tmux ls | grep -vq attached && tmux at -t $( tmux ls | grep -vm1 attached | cut -d: -f1 ) ) || tmux new
}
```

But that doesn't work, per the original question above.

My solution so far is to have a wrapper script on the host servers:

```
tmux-reattach-if-exists
```

which consists simply of:

```
(tmux ls | grep -vq attached && tmux at -t $( tmux ls | grep -vm1 attached | cut -d: -f1 )) || tmux new
```

Then I used called the script on the client from mosh like this:

```
function tmosh() {
    mosh $1 -- tmux-reattach-if-exists
}
```

If there's a solution that can do this via .tmux.conf directly that would be great but I couldn't seem to work that out.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the end of your `.bashrc`

```
s1="`ps $PPID|grep mosh|awk '{print $5}'`"
s2=mosh-server
if [[ "$s1" == "$s2" ]]; then source .moshrc; fi
```

If called by `mosh-server`, `bash` will execute whatever it finds in `$HOME/.moshrc` - so just put your commands in a file named `.moshrc` in your home directory.

Because mosh invokes a login shell, you should have a line

```
source .bashrc
```

in your `.bash_profile`, or put the above lines in `.bash_profile`.